# Selenium error - Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am trying to automate a shopping website and selected a phone to add in cart, but while changing the ram its continuously showing the same message that its unable to locate the element.I have tried with both implicit wait and explicit wait but the result is same. i also tried with JavaScriptexecuter but same is coming.

here is the code i am trying -

```
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    search.sendKeys("mi note10 pro max");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/button")).click();
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/div/a")).click();

    

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    WebElement ram = w.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[2]")));
    
    //WebElement ram2 = driver.findElement(By.className("_3V2wfe"));
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ram);
    ram.getText();
    ram.click();
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you use the xPath with a lot of divs. That can work but only with static pages, every time a page reloads or updates, the schema of the divs may vary and that's maybe your case. I'll strongly advice you to change the wait you inform selenium the object you want to search, using e.g. `TagName` property.

Comment: @Kumar Please provide the website link, so it could be investigated

Comment: @AnandGautam check with flipkart and try to check and if u get the result then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could work on python selenium and not Java, so I did the same. Nevertheless, the locator strategies would remain same everywhere. So, as @osfresia mentioned, the usage of long xpaths is not a good practice. You must keep the xpaths as narrowly relative as possible. Having said that, here is my code written in Python Selenium. Feel free to pick up the xpath and work it out.
Also, I do not have much time at this point to pick up all your code and test (for I now, just took the first element, and it didn't detect for me). So I used my own search - a direct search link of the item, which I think would not bother you much as you are looking for the RAM element, so you can pick it up from this code below.

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-10-pro-max-vintage-bronze-128-gb/p/itmfcdaff39806aa?pid=MOBGF47CJET6F85E&lid=LSTMOBGF47CJET6F85EVCJXV5&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=mi+note+10+pro+max&store=tyy%2F4io&srno=s_1_1&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_10_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_10_na_na_na&fm=SEARCH&iid=ef203add-2f6c-4963-a378-2b6da0fcd440.MOBGF47CJET6F85E.SEARCH&ppt=hp&ppn=homepage&ssid=9qtkzqbc1s0000001641541609979&qH=7b846a424b01e817")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='RAM']//parent::div//a[text()='8 GB']").click()
```

Output:
Initially it was on 6GB (default selected), then it clicks on 8GB using the above code.
[image: Snapshot]

One more thing, if you search opens in a new window, then you may have to use window handles if required.